# nginx forwards every incoming request to upstream if its returning 5xx, can it be throttled?

Tags: caching, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use nginx for caching responses for 1 minute. Following is the config:

```
proxy_pass http://myupstream.com;
proxy_set_header Host myupstream.com
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_cache mycache;
proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri$http_accept_encoding;
proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
proxy_cache_lock on;
```

With this config, nginx serves from cache when the upstream returns 5xx responses which is good. However my problem is that when upstreams starts returning 5xx and the cache has expired, every incoming request is forwarded to upstream putting immense load on the upstream servers which are already not in a good state (that they are responding with 5xx). Can nginx be configured to forward requests to upstream once every 1 minute even when upstream responds with 5xx. I have added the following line but with no avail:

```
proxy_cache_valid 500 502 503 504 1m;
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: If upstream is already loaded then you should be adding more capacity to upstream

Comment: I have put the required reverse proxy capacity to handle exactly this load. Its a problem to have this kind of spiky traffic to the backend and that too when the backend is unstable.